# Why do I get error when I do optional chaining?

Tags: swift, option-type, optional-chaining

```
protocol textingprotocol : class {
    func didEnterText (text:String)
}

class secondViewController: UIViewController {    
weak var delegate:textingprotocol?

@IBOutlet weak var txtField: UITextField?

@IBAction func dismissButton(sender: UIButton) {

    delegate!.didEnterText(txtField?.text) // A: doesn't work
    delegate!.didEnterText(txtField?.text!) // B: doesn't work
    delegate!.didEnterText((txtField?.text)!) // C: works

}
```

A: Am I not already doing *optional chaining* and the line would only work if text has a value if not then it would gracefully fail?
Yet it gives:

> Value of optional type 'String?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use
>   '!' or '?'?

B: Even when I am given compiler error of above, well I do unwrap it, still it's not satisfied it wants it to be like C. To my understanding with the `?` I have unwrapped txtField and with the `!` I have unwrapped text, still confused why it doesn't work

Why does C work but not B? Isn't there a more cleaner way than line C? Line C looks very unappealing.

Comment: should be `@IBOutlet weak var txtField: UITextField!`

Comment: @LeoDabus Hah. thanks. but looking into the `text` property. Why is that an optional? I mean why I Cmmd+click it it shows `@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *text;` it doesn't show anything of like `text:String?` how is it underneath from Objective-c translated to an optional?

Comment: I'm no swift expert, so I'll leave a comment rather than an answer... `didEnterText` requires a non-nil value, so my understanding is that with option B if `txtField` is nil the `.text` part of that statement wouldn't even be evaluated, and as such adding the `.text!` doesn't fix the issue of a nil text field. In option C all the compiler sees is a value that is "guaranteed" to be non-nil because the whole thing is wrapped in parens...

Comment: How is `textingprotocol` defined, please?

Comment: @matt see the update

Comment: So this is some form of Swift 2?

Comment: @matt not sure :| , but on my Xcode 8, I have enabled `Use Legacy Swift Language Version` to be able to use 2.x, though when I do `xcrun swift -version` I get `Apple Swift version 3.0 `

Comment: Right, I understand. :) Okay, I'm ready to answer, hang on a sec.

Comment: @matt Thanks boss. Experts like you help newbies like me make our livings. Super thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`didEnterText` does not take a `String?`. It takes a `String`. Thus, you cannot use simple optional chaining with question marks to get its argument. You must *actually* unwrap to a `String`, not *tentatively* unwrap to a `String?`-or-nil.

Now, `txtField` is an Optional, so you need to unwrap it.

And a UITextField's `text` property is an Optional, so you need to unwrap it too.

So the simplest approach is to unwrap them both, absolutely:

```
    delegate!.didEnterText(txtField!.text!)
```

If you don't want to do that (because you fear that one of them will be nil and crash your app), you will have to protect the whole thing with `if let`:

```
    if let s = txtField?.text {
        delegate!.didEnterText(s)
    }
```

Comment: so basically you are saying an non-optional will NEVER work with optionals unless it's guaranteed by using `!` ie not `?` right?

Comment: I don't quite know what you mean. The simple fact is that you cannot supply a `String?` where a `String` is expected. The `String` is hidden inside the `String?`. You must unwrap it! You can unwrap it unsafely with `!` or safely and conditionally with `if let`, but you must unwrap it before you can use it.

Comment: It almost seems as if you are not entirely clear on what an Optional _is_. If that's the case, my book will help you: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch03.html#_optional

Comment: :) perhaps. I thought I knew, but it's the optional chaining part that is confusing, but now it seems that if you try to unwrap a value through `?` you can't assign that value to something that is non-optional. Since it's not guaranteeing a value—it could *still* be nil.

Comment: Optional chaining with `?` has the advantage that you won't crash, but it can only end up with an Optional. You still need to unwrap it! It think that might be the fact that you are missing.